# Getting org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: Connection reset when running Karate Tests

Tags: testing, karate

Getting connection reset error all of a sudden. When running karate tests. Was running perfectly fine before.
01: new tokenGenerator().generateToken(appIdSC,secretSC,tokenUrl,accountsScope,'POST')
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: Connection reset

- java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
- java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
- sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)

Here is how the java class is being read in feature file to get token:
Background:

- def tokenGenerator = Java.type('Utility.JwtTokenGenerator')
- def authHeader = new tokenGenerator().generateToken(appIdSC,secretSC,tokenUrl,accountsScope,'POST')

Background:

- def tokenGenerator = Java.type('Utility.JwtTokenGenerator')
- def authHeader = new tokenGenerator().generateToken(appIdSC,secretSC,tokenUrl,accountsScope,'POST')

Expected it to run as usual

Comment: my personal opinion: this is the kind of question where unless you follow this process you won't be able to get any help: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I am not able to replicate in the sample project

Comment: Oh got the resolution, there was a API update at the JWT token client end. Working fine after updating it